How to go from human readable date format ('YYYY-MM-DD') to datetime format string ("%Y-%m-%d")
I would like to allow the user to specify the date format using a human readable format like 'YYYY-MM-DD'. But then I need to actually parse dates so I need the corresponding actual datetime format '%Y-%m-%d'. Is there a way go from the first to the second?

Related: Convert Java date format (yyyy) to Python (%Y) (no good answer though)

You can use a dictionary to convert human readable format or your custom format to strftime.
import datetime


def human_to_strftime(human_format):
    format_mapping = {
        'YYYY': '%Y',
        'YY': '%y',
        'MM': '%m',
        'DD': '%d',
        'HH': '%H',
        'MI': '%M',
        'SS': '%S',
        'AM/PM': '%p'
    }
    strftime_format = human_format
    for human, strftime in format_mapping.items():
        strftime_format = strftime_format.replace(human, strftime)
    return strftime_format


if __name__ == "__main__":
    date = "2024-07-09"
    date_format = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    spec = human_to_strftime(date_format)
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, spec)
    print(datetime_obj)

Output:
2024-07-09 00:00:00


Maybe this is unimportant, but why are you calling it just "strftime" when those format codes are used by strftime and strptime?

I used strftime because I'm referencing to the format (strFtime) not to the parsing (strPtime).

Is that what the F means? I thought it might be "from" as in "string from time". Vs strptime = "string parse to time". I guess it'd be clearer if they called them "time2str" and "str2time" :p
